# How to address a text field created within a symbol from main timeline in Flash using actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How to address a text field created within a symbol from main timeline in Flash using actionscript?

For example, if I have a text field named textfield inside a symbol named symbol1, which is input inside a movie clip called movieclip1, which is, of course, on the main timeline, what could I use to make the textfield half size of the movieclip?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a linkage name to the textField in the library first. Let's say you give it a linkage name of `title`. Now you can do

```
title.width = title.parent.parent.width/2;
```

Comment: How can I assign a linkage name to the text field? From what I see, only the symbol is in the library, not the text field which is inside of the symbol.

Comment: As far as I remember, put an instance of the symbol on your scene, select it, and then in properties panel on the right you should find a text field for inputting an instance name. Been long since I used flash though :D

Comment: @Monden yeah google "where do I put linkage name in Flash?"

Comment: @Monden so I think maybe textFields don't get linkage names? You've given it an instance name... so just access the symbol or movieclip it's in and do like `movieClip.textFieldName.text = "Hello World";`

Comment: After I've right-clicked on the symbol, the only option that had anything to do with linkage is "ActionScript Linkage" under "Properties". The only thing I can do there is to tick "Export for ActionScript", which then makes a Class with the symbol name. I don't know if I'm on the right track...

Comment: Thanks, Neal. That does it.